# Centre Align CAShape layer in a UIView

Tags: ios, cashapelayer

The following is a image for which the the code does not align the centre of the UIView , white color.

```
CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

layer.path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75.0, 75.0)].CGPath;
layer.fillColor =[UIColor redColor].CGColor;

[self.shapeView.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`anchorPoint` is not for setting the position of CAShapeLayer, use `position` instead.

```
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
layer.borderWidth = 100

layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
layer.position = myView.center
layer.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

**Edit**

Sorry for such a rough answer before, the code above may not work as you want, here is the correct answer I just come out. A important thing to note is: **How you draw the oval path did effect the position of your `CAShapeLayer`**

```
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
myView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
layer.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
layer.position = CGPointMake(myView.layer.bounds.midX, myView.layer.bounds.midY)
layer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(-75.0 / 2, -75.0 / 2, 75.0, 75.0)).CGPath
```

From Apple Document,

> The oval path is created in a clockwise direction (relative to the default
>   coordinate system)

In other word, the oval path is drawn from the edge instead of the center, so you must take into accound the radius of the oval you are drawing. In your case, you need to do this:

```
layer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(-75.0 / 2, -75.0 / 2, 75.0, 75.0)).CGPath
```

Now we ensure that the center of drawn path is equal to the center of `CAShapeLayer`. Then we can use `position` property to move the `CAShapeLayer` as we want. The image below could help you understand.

[image] [image]

Comment: This answer worked but I had to add it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and within that method I had to call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` before adding the above code

Answer (score 0):

```
CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

layer.path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake((self.shapeView.frame.size.width/2)-37.5, (self.shapeView.frame.size.height/2)-37.5, 75.0, 75.0)].CGPath;
//37.5 means width & height divided by 2
layer.fillColor =[UIColor redColor].CGColor;

[self.shapeView.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

Answer (score 0):

For those still have issue with centering this approach worked for me:

1- Set the shape layer frame equal to parent view frame.

```
shapeLayer.frame = view.frame
```

2- remove the shape layer position property.

```
// shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: ,y: )
```

3- set x and y value of your bezier path equal to zero.

```
UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.width, height: 
self.height))
```

Only these should be enough, get rid of the rest.

======

If that didn't work, then try this one:

```
@IBDesignable class YourView: UIView {

private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    self.shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    self.shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

    let bezierPathHeight = self.bezierPath.cgPath.boundingBox.height
    let bezierPathWidth = self.bezierPath.cgPath.boundingBox.width

    self.shapeLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: self.bounds.width / bezierPathWidth, y: self.bounds.height / bezierPathHeight))

    self.shapeLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: self.bounds.width / bezierPathHeight, y: self.bounds.height / bezierPathHeight))

    self.layer.addSublayer(self.shapeLayer)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter same case like this. The final resolution is `shapeLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true` and update CAShapeLayer frame in `layoutSubviews`, CenteredAlignShapeView can adjust when using Auto Layout.

```
class CenteredAlignShapeView: UIView {
    
    public let dot = CAShapeLayer()
 
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        dot.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
        layer.insertSublayer(dot, at: 0)
        dot.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        dot.frame = bounds
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2), radius: 4, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi*2, clockwise: true)
        dot.path = circlePath.cgPath
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```